# Why didn't Weeping Angels kill Sally Sparrow when she grabbed TARDIS key?

Tags: doctor-who

In the Doctor Who episode "Blink", when [Sally Sparrow](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Sally_Sparrow_%28Blink%29) took TARDIS key from the hand of a *weeping angel*, she didn't know anything about them. Honestly, it's not exactly in my mind that she was looking at that time or not, but she couldn't actively gaze them as she didn't know about the rules.

The area was also far from any population, so there was no-one looking at the Weeping Angels. Without anyone looking at them, they were free from the "quantum lock" to kill anyone.

Why didn't they kill Sally Sparrow at that time?

Comment: Didn't they need someone to open the Tardis in order for them to be able to access the Heart of the Tardis?

Comment: @Monty129 Why would they need other when they were locomotive like us (when not locked)? When they had TARDIS key, they didn't have TARDIS.

Comment: It's been awhile since I've seen that episode, but I thought the Doctor mentioned something about needing a human to access the Tardis for them because of security measures, which is why they kept luring Sally to the house in the first place.

Comment: Because Wheeping Angels never kill their victims. The Doctor once even cares to point out how kind of a predator they are because of that.

Comment: @user1129682 Turn that into an answer...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may have missed it, but the angels are locking *each other*. When Sally moves between them, the two that are farther away take the opportunity to cover their eyes, leaving the closer one (the one with the key) to attack her as soon as her back is turned.

[image]
[image]

The closest Angel was about to touch her back (presumably to eradicate her) when she heard the door and darted forward, out of reach. Before it had time to react, she'd already run down the stairs.

Comment: This is plain simple Wrong. Once locked with each other, they couldn't be free again because they couldn't blink or hide eyes in locked state leaving other in locked state. And, this is how they were beaten in the end.

Comment: Let's call them a, b and c. In the first frame, all three are locked. Sally steps between a and b which allows b to cover its eyes. She then steps between a and c which allows c to cover its eyes. She turns her back on a, allowing it to move.

Comment: The question is: Why didn't a (which raised hand) kill Sally?

Comment: @SachinShekhar - It was reaching towards her when she heard the door. She ran forward and the angel (just) missed touching her. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hold on a second.. Are you saying that for one of the fastest creatures alive? Blink and they are gone...

Comment: @SachinShekhar - The Dr Who wiki says that they slow down when approaching their target, 'enjoying the kill'

Comment: That's nonsense... But, looks compatible with the end scenes when they were trying to kill. Accepting the answer.

Comment: One thing I've noticed in the episodes is that the camera is treated as an observer - if the camera can see an angel, the angel is quantum locked.  It actually gave me a bit of a chill when I realized that - like I was actually involved with the episode, simply by watching.

Comment: @Jeff - Except that they go and ruin it in a later episode by having the angels move.

Comment: @Valorum Considering that television is only 24 FPS, while many people are used to watching things that are at least 30 FPS, they can move for _at least_ 1/20 of a second, every second, even if the audience is looking directly at them, in between the individual frames.  With their speed, that's _more_ than enough.

Answer (score 1):

The weeping angles in blink wanted to consume the time energy from TARDIS that is why they had the key but the police had the TARDIS in storage; they might not have know where the TARDIS was and used Sally to find the TARDIS.

Comment: Sally found TARDIS by luck.

Comment: That what the angles want you to think

Answer (score -2):

The Angels need her to open the Tardis for them. They have the key why didn't they open the Tardis? They need her.

Comment: Are you suggesting that Angels can't open TARDIS? This is absurd. The real reason they didn't open the TARDIS because they didn't know where the TARDIS was.

Comment: @ILoveYou Not necessarily.  The Doctor might've installed failsafes to keep it from being opened by anyone other than himself or a human, for all we know.